# How to get full file path in form upload field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the full upload path in a file upload field. I attached a change lister to the upload field, when a file is selected I alert the file path and I get just the file name. Not the full file path as it appears in the form field. For example instead of this:

```
C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\me.jpg
```

I get

```
me.jpg
```

the code:

```
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
        var fileLocation = $(this).val();
        alert(fileLocation);
    });
```

How to get the full file path?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You could possibly write a flash or java app to do it, but you can't in javascript.

Comment: hmm, but the file path is right there displayed inside the file upload field. I'm not asking to get the path directly by forming a link with the computer, just to grab that piece of text that's already there in the upload field. Is there really no other way?

Comment: that is a security restriction of the browser, you cannot get the full path of the file.